# What does "it" imply?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> But it soon soured, and by the end of last season, which the Rockets finished 41-41, it was clear that Houston had one too many top dogs in the locker room. "It was confusing," says Rockets guard Patrick Beverley. "I've got Dwight telling me I need **it** in the post, I got James telling me I need **it** on the wing."

http://time.com/4672996/james-harden-rule-nba/

Comment: I made a small correction to your quotation.  Please don't add quote marks to quoted text if they weren't in the original - the whole point of quoting text is that it's what appears in the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without context, it's hard to know what "it" refers to.  Because the passage refers to basketball and is referring to what players are (supposedly) saying in game; I'd say that "it" refers to the basketball.

I hope this helps,

-J

Comment: There is a link below. Could you take a look?

Comment: I've read it, now.  The context is certainly that it is the ball.  "I need it in the post".  "I need it on the wing".  These both refer to needing the ball.  Let's try a substitution, "I need (the ball) in the post".  "I need (the ball) on the wing".